# Get XML value dynamically

Tags: powershell, group-policy

I am writing a script to get gpo data and store it a PSObject. I am stuck on getting the value of the property dynamically. I have the following code. Whey I call the $obj and use expand with the name as a string it works. When I run it with the loop, it errors out

```
# Generate GPO Report
$GPOReport = Get-GPO -All | %{
    [xml](Get-GPOReport -Guid $_.Id -ReportType Xml)
}

# Blank Array to  store PSObject
$arr = @()

# Loop through each of the reports
foreach($GPOR in $GPOReport){

    $PSObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject

    # Policy Meta Data
    $PolicyName = $GPOR.GPO.Name
    $Created = $GPOR.GPO.CreatedTime -split 'T'
    $Modified = $GPOR.GPO.ModifiedTime -split 'T'

    # Policy Settings
    $ComputerPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension)
    $UserPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.User.ExtensionData.Extension)

    if($ComputerPolicy){
         $obj = $ComputerPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
         switch($obj.GetType().name){
            'Object[]'{
                $obj | %{
                    $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name | Out-String
                    if($Name){
                        $_  | Select -ExpandProperty $Name
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
    
    if($UserPolicy){
        $obj = $UserPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
        switch($obj.GetType().name){
            'Object[]'{
               $obj | %{
                    $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name | Out-String
                    if($Name){
                        $_  | Select -ExpandProperty $Name
                    }
                }
            }
         }
    }
}
```

getting the objects value

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to figure out the issue. Since the Name variable was being loaded as a string and object, I found that I needed to loop though that as well. This was able to solve my issue.

Here is a full working model for everyone else to enjoy.

```
# Generate GPO Report
$GPOReport = Get-GPO -All | %{
    [xml](Get-GPOReport -Guid $_.Id -ReportType Xml)
}

# Blank Array to  store PSObject
$arr = @()


# Loop through each of the reports
foreach($GPOR in $GPOReport){

    # Policy Meta Data
    $PolicyName = $GPOR.GPO.Name
    $Created = $GPOR.GPO.CreatedTime -split 'T'
    $Modified = $GPOR.GPO.ModifiedTime -split 'T'

    # Policy Settings
    $ComputerPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.Computer.ExtensionData.Extension)
    $UserPolicy = ($GPOR.GPO.User.ExtensionData.Extension)

    if($ComputerPolicy){
        
        $obj = $ComputerPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
        switch($obj.GetType().name){
            'Object[]'{
                $obj | %{
                    $PSObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PolicyName -NotePropertyValue $PolicyName
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Created -NotePropertyValue $Created[0]
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Modified -NotePropertyValue $Modified[0]

                    $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name
                    $LoadObj = $_
                
                    $Name | %{
                        if($_){
                            $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $LoadObj.$_
                        }
                    }
                    $arr += $PSObject
                }
            }
         }
    }
    
    if($UserPolicy){
        $obj = $UserPolicy | Select-Xml  -XPath * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
        switch($obj.GetType().name){
            'Object[]'{
                $obj | %{
                    $PSObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName PolicyName -NotePropertyValue $PolicyName
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Created -NotePropertyValue $Created[0]
                    $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Modified -NotePropertyValue $Modified[0]

                    $Name = ($_ | gm -MemberType property | select Name).Name
                    $LoadObj = $_
                
                    $Name | %{
                        if($_){
                            $PSObject | Add-Member -NotePropertyName $_ -NotePropertyValue $LoadObj.$_
                        }
                    }
                    $arr += $PSObject
                }
            }
         }
    }
}

$arr | Select PolicyName,
    Name,
    State,
    Explain,
    Created,
    Modified,
    Category,
    Supported | Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\GPOResults.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem reading the XML data, as there's no XSL or data model we could find for it so we've made one if anyone is interested.

https://david-homer.blogspot.com/2023/08/accessing-group-policy-object-settings.html